# Linked List, can only access child one level down

Tags: linked-list

I'm currently having a problem with my with my linked list where I can access the left child and right of my current node, but if I access the child's child, I receive the same data as the child. I assume that the left and right child of the child is set to itself for some odd reason, but I am not certain why that is. I have a min heap that pops out two class objects, and then those objects are made into the left and right child of the node I am creating, what I'm trying to create is a huffman tree. Here is the pusedo code for it;

```
for(if i is less than the heapsize)
{
  pop node1;//pops out a object not a pointer.
  pop node2;
  node parent = node(sum of both frequencies, address of node1, address of node2)
  //allocation of new memory for parent.
  insert(parent)
}
```

I know it has to be an address problem because if I go through my min_heap and check the left and right childs of those objects, it correctly points to it's left and right child.

LL implementation

```
node.h
class node
{
private:
int data;
public:
node* left_child;
node* right_child;
node();
node(int,node*,node*);
}
node.cpp
node::node()
{
left_child = NULL;
right_child = NULL;
}
node::node(int temp,node* temp, node* temp2)
{
  data = temp;
  left_child = temp;
  right_child = temp2;
}
```

Comment: Can we see your LL implementation? What Language is this in?

Comment: I just noticed all my nodes have the same left and right child. I think its a storage of the linked list issue, could it be because I am popping a object which  is called the node instead of a pointer?

Comment: I found the problem when i set the left child to the node, I did not allocate memory for that.....